# Deleting duplicates after n-occurrences

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

As a generalization of `DeleteDuplicates`, I want to delete duplicates from a list, but only after `n` number of duplicates.

Say, `n = 3` means that three duplicates are allowed.

I made my own function:

```
DeleteDuplicatesN[x_, n_] := 
  x[[
    Sort[
      Flatten[#[[1 ;; Min[Length[#], n]]]& /@ 
       (Flatten[Position[x, #]]& /@ DeleteDuplicates[x])]]]]

DeleteDuplicatesN[{1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 7, 4, 7, 1}, 3]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 4, 7}
> ```

Is there a better method — faster or more elegant?

For example, using only `DeleteDuplicates` or `DeleteDuplicatesBy`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you'll find this faster:

```
dd[list_, n_] := 
  Module[{pi = Flatten[Values[PositionIndex[list][[All, ;; UpTo@n]]]]},
   list[[Sort@pi]]];
```

Using `RandomInteger[20000, 20000]` as a test list and allowing 3 duplicates, your code took ~37 seconds, this needed ~0.03 seconds.

Comparable in speed, simpler:

```
dd2[list_, n_] := 
  list[[Union @@ 
     GatherBy[Range@Length@list, list[[#]] &][[All, ;; UpTo@n]]]];
```

For large lists that aren't grossly duplicated elements, this offers a performance edge (e.g., with `RandomInteger[10000000,20000000]` test list, over 6X speed of above methods):

```
dd=Module[{o = Ordering@#},
 o[[o]] = Join @@ Range[Tally[#[[o]]][[All, 2]]];
 Pick[#, UnitStep[#2 - o], 1]]&;
```

Comment: Nice. If nobody comes with a better code in a day or so I will accept your answer.

Comment: We can use `Sort[pi]` instead of `pi[[Ordering[pi]]]`. If I am not mistaken it is the same speed but more transparent code.

Comment: @azerbajdzan - yes, that function was snipped from some code that used the ordering later. I've made the readability change.

Comment: Maybe this is a good one for the Function Repository?

Comment: @ciao: Never thought `UnitStep` could be useful in list manipulations :-D

Comment: @ciao: Your last code seems to need some corrections. There are no arguments inside `dd`. Or was it intention?

Comment: @azerbajdzan - ?
It is written as a pure function - the `slot` *are* the arguments.
It is called the same way as the other examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 7, 4, 7, 1};
```

Using `DeleteElements` (new in 13.1)

```
p = Rule @@ Reverse /@ Cases[Tally @ list + Threaded[{0, -3}], {_, _?Positive}]
```

{3, 1} -> {1, 5}

Delete 3 ones and 1 five

```
Reverse @ DeleteElements[Reverse @ list, p]
```

{1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 4, 7}

Since `DeleteElements` works from left to right we have to `Reverse`
twice

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 7, 4, 7, 1};
```

---

A variant of the first accepted answer:

```
list[[Union @@ PositionIndex[list][[All, ;; UpTo[3]]]]] // RepeatedTiming

(*{0.0000210309, {1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 4, 7}}*)

list[[Sort@
    Flatten[Values[
      PositionIndex[list][[All, ;; UpTo[3]]]]]]] // RepeatedTiming

(*{0.0000263463, {1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 4, 7}}*)
```

Another variant using `Tally`:

```
list[[Union @@ Tally[PositionIndex[list]][[All, 1, ;; UpTo[3]]]]]

(*{1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 4, 7}*)
```